# Reinstalling macOS from recovery uses extra space?

Tags: macos, partition, apfs, ventura

When you use the option to reinstall macOS from recovery, it uses an extra 10GB of space. I restored the same data using Migration assistant, but after it shows about 10 GB less space available. Originally, it was using an extra 15GB, but I was able to remove /System/Volumes/Data/macOS Install Data, which cleared 5GB, even though it said it was 11.6GB.

It shows that the Macintosh HD partition is no longer using an APFS snapshot, sort of. It says it's still using an snapshot, but it doesn't show it in the snapshot list like it was doing before.

When I use a disk space analyzer like Disk Inventory X or Grand Perspective, it doesn't show where the extra space is being used. Apparently, the /System folder is using space on the partition for another copy of an OS install, not just the data it dynamically creates that aren't in the snapshot. But the APFS snapshot of the OS is still there as well.

Container disk3 -> Macintosh HD -> Macintosh HD is greyed out, but it says "System snapshot mounted" and it shows the APFS name "com.apple.os.update-BACB...", same as before. But the list of snapshots in Disk Utility is empty for all of the volumes; it doesn't show an OS/system snapshot in the list like it was showing before.

If you try to erase a partition in Disk Utility in recovery mode, it gives you an option to "erase mac". Then it reinstalls. I tried using this option, but it's the same situation.

How do I reclaim the extra space that's being used? It seems like there is an extra copy of the operating system files that are being stored on the data partition, when they weren't before. It apparently still has an OS/system snapshot, but it's not clear if it's mounting that and using that, or the files stored on the data partition.

Comment: How are you measuring this 10 GB of extra usage? Is it using `diskutil list` or another tool perhaps?

Comment: Also, be sure to edit in a clear question at the end of your question. This reads like a blog post or a start of an answer more than a clear question as recommended in the [tour].